# init string constants by reflection

Tags: java, string, reflection, constants

I am refactoring some old code and find a class "Tags" containing string constants, most of them tags used by some XML-Parser-Handlers. But also for serialising data. They are defined blank:

> public static String PROXY, NAME, X, Y, KEY, ... CODES;

and initialized by their own name:

```
static {
    Field[] fields = Tags.class.getFields();
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; ++i) {
        try {
            // init field by its lowercased name
            String value = fields[i].getName().toLowerCase();
            fields[i].set(null, value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // exception should not occur, because only strings over here.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Does it make sense in your opinion?
Pros:

- all tags in one place
- guaranteed correspondence between name & value (no mistyping)
- support by IDE autocompletion when typing

Cons:

- not really constants (not final)
- readability -- to just use the string literals "proxy", "name" etc. would be more straightforward
- the initialisation by reflection consumes processing time -- delays startup time

So -- keep it or refactor it?

Comment: I would probably try to use `enum` for this.

Comment: Boy this sounds a lot like ENUM values. Why not figure out a way to use an ENUM with these as its values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
enum Enum {
    PROXY, NAME, X, Y;
    public String toString() { 
        return name().toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

or this:

```
public enum Tags {
    proxy, name, x, y
}
```

Comment: thanks, Mikhail! I converted the Strings to enums. Nice idea to overload the `toString()`.

Answer (score 4):

You can replace these constants by an enum and still keep the advantages you've listed:

```
public enum Tags {
    PROXY("proxy"), 
    NAME("name"), 
    X("x"), 
    Y("y");

    public final String value;

    private Tags(String value) {
        this.value = value;

        if (!value.equals(name().toLowerCase())) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Value and name do not match");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (Tags tag : Tags.values()) {
            System.out.println(tag + "\t" + tag.value);
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above, the test `value.equals(name().toLowerCase())` is not necessary but you seem concerned about mistyping errors